# Determining Hurst exponent of a Brownian motion

Tags: time-series, programming, brownian-motion, hurst-exponent

I am trying to determine the Hurst exponent of a simple Brownian motion, however, I seem to get a result that differs from 0.5. I am following the instructions given on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurst_exponent#Estimating_the_exponent)-page, and here is the code I wrote in R for determining it:

```
library(ggplot2)

#generate Brownian motion
t <- 1:1e3
sig2 <- 0.01
x <- rnorm(n = length(t) - 1, sd = sqrt(sig2))
data <- c(0, cumsum(x))

#function to find Hurst exponent
simpleHurst <- function(y){
  sd.y <- sd(y)
  m <- mean(y)
  y <- y - m
  max.y <- max(cumsum(y))
  min.y <- min(cumsum(y))
  RS <- (max.y - min.y)/sd.y
  return(RS)
}

#find Hurst exponent of Brownian motion
df.rs <- data.frame()
for(i in c(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32)){
  RS <- 0
  n <- floor((length(data)/i))
  for(j in 0:(i-1)){
    X <- data[(1:n) + j*n]
    RS <- RS + simpleHurst(y = X)
  }

  df.rs <- rbind(df.rs, 
                 data.frame("log.t" = log(length(X)),
                            "log.RS"= log(RS / n)))
}

ggplot(data=df.rs,  aes(x=log.t, y=log.RS)) + geom_point(size=I(2))
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]

This doesn't converge to 0.5 obviously. Is there an error in the script, or do I simply need to analyze a (much) longer time-series?

Comment: Please don’t `rm` people’s workspace, edited .

Comment: @BobJansen Good point, deleted it

Comment: @BobJansen I'm very determined to solve this problem, so whatever speeds up the process :)

Comment: `fit <- lm(log.RS ~ log.t, data = df.rs)` Just make sure the reference cited in wikipedia uses the same definition of $H$. According to this fit $H=-1$

Comment: @caverac So you believe the above script is correct?

Comment: It certainly calculates $H$ according to wikipedia, whether this number matches what [these](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0007011.pdf) (c.f. wikipedia's reference list) authors mean is a whole other story

Comment: caverac has answered this above - it's the slope of the graph you are after rather than it converging to a value. Something like slope = H - 1